# create folder on remote EC2 Instance using Jsch

Tags: java, ssh, amazon-ec2, jsch

I want to create a folder on a remote EC2 instance from another EC2 Instance and then copy some data into it as well.

I tried to create folder using JSch and passing command `sudo mkdir /data` but the error I get is `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.Without sudo also, I am unable to create folder. I tried to use `((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true)` and by using this I can create the folder but afterwards I am unable to copy any data and even cant ssh the EC2 Instance from commandline .(if i create folder manualy then copying data is done successfully). can someone please guide me that what should be the way to do it.Thanks

Comment: Here at a RHEL 6.3 instance, everything works perfectly with setPty(true);

Comment: how do you stop pseudoterminal. do you use simply setPty(false) or need to do something else also?

Answer (score 0):

How about following example?

```
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968805/use-of-jsch-sudo-example-and-channel-setpty-for-running-sudo-command-on-remote-h

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JSch. But if you have root access, you can update your sudoers configuration file to get around this.  Add the following line to /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults:USERNAME_HERE !requiretty
```

Maybe someone else can elaborate on whether this is a bad idea or not, that's beyond the scope of my knowledge, but I'd love to know more?

I only use this approcah in one specific situation.  We have a cronjob that backs up a cluster of remote servers via rsync, but for rsync to run successfully, it needs sudo privileges.

To get around this I did the following-

1. Created a user "backupuser" - On both servers local & remote
2. Added the following two lines to /etc/sudoers - Only needed on the server you want to grant sudo privileges to the user on.  In our case, only on the remote server.

   ```
   backupuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
   DEFAULTS:backupuser !requiretty
   ```

Adding these two lines grants the user, 'backupuser' sudo privileges for rsync command without the need to enter a password and without the required tty connection.

Here's how it works-

The first line breaks down into two parts.

```
USER SPECIFICATION OPTION_TAG (: CONDITIONS(opt))
```

1. USER SPECIFICATION - this sets the user that these options apply(s) too.

   ```
   backupuser
   ```
2. OPTION_TAG - the tag for the option you what to grant.  In this case, the user is granted sudo privileges without having the enter a password. (see ***man sudoers*** for a list of tags available)

   ```
   ALL = NOPASSWD
   ```
3. CONDITIONS - You also have the option to place conditions on when to grant sudo privileges.  In this case, the user only has sudo privileges to run the rsync command.

   ```
   : /usr/bin/rsync
   ```

The second line, overrides the default requirement of the sudo command that you need a terminal connection to run sudo (tty requirement).  And it grants this privilege only to the user account 'backupuser'.  (See ***man sudoers*** for the other DEFAULTS)

```
DEFAULTS:backupuser !requiretty
```

Hope this helps answer your question. I know it went on a bit of a tangent, but I wanted to give a full explanation. For more info you can also checkout ***man sudo***

Comment: Alan thanks for the detailed answer but I think it wont work for me as I am creating EC2 instances on the run and cant change anything in /etc/sudoers without changing its permission settings and for that again I need to use sudo