# Running here-doc command using JSch

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to run following commands using JSch:

```
sudo su - someuser << EOF
whoami
EOF
```

To execute command I'm using this method:

```
public String exec(String command) {
    StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        Channel channelInstance = this.session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channelInstance).setCommand(command);
        InputStream commandOutput = channelInstance.getInputStream();
        channelInstance.connect();
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();
        while (readByte != 0xffffffff) {
            outputBuffer.append((char) readByte);
            readByte = commandOutput.read();
        }
        channelInstance.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ioX) {
        System.out.println(ioX.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (JSchException jschX) {
        System.out.println(jschX.getMessage());
        return null;
    } 
    return outputBuffer.toString();
}
```

Now, using `exec()` i want to pass here-doc command i.e:

```
exec("sudo su - someuser << EOF\nwhoami\nEOF");
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried different combinations and none of them worked.

Do you have any ideas how to execute here-doc command via JSch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run `sudo` command. I have copied an example from [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples)
and then made some modification (`((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);`) using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968805/use-of-jsch-sudo-example-and-channel-setpty-for-running-sudo-command-on-remote-h) example.

Below is my code and it's working for me:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Exec {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            String host = null;
            if (arg.length > 0) {
                host = arg[0];
            } else {
                host = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                        System.getProperty("user.name") + "@localhost");
            }
            String user = host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
            host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@') + 1);

            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo su - chatar << EOF\nwhoami\nEOF");
             ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();

            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    if (in.available() > 0)
                        continue;
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "
                            + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {
        public String getPassword() {
            return passwd;
        }

        public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
            Object[] options = { "yes", "no" };
            int foo = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, str, "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
            return foo == 0;
        }

        String passwd;
        JTextField passwordField = (JTextField) new JPasswordField(20);

        public String getPassphrase() {
            return null;
        }

        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
            Object[] ob = { passwordField };
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                passwd = passwordField.getText();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void showMessage(String message) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        }

        final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        private Container panel;

        public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                String name, String instruction, String[] prompt, boolean[] echo) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;

            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

            JTextField[] texts = new JTextField[prompt.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]), gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                if (echo[i]) {
                    texts[i] = new JTextField(20);
                } else {
                    texts[i] = new JPasswordField(20);
                }
                panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
            }

            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, destination + ": "
                    + name, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                String[] response = new String[prompt.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                    response[i] = texts[i].getText();
                }
                return response;
            } else {
                return null; // cancel
            }
        }
    }
}
```