# How to pass in the password to scp using Java ssh JSch and jcabi-ssh

Tags: java, ssh, scp, jsch, jcabi

I need to execute following command:

```
scp -r ~/dataIn yatsuk@192.168.1.1:~/dataOut
```

In Ubuntu (16.04) terminal this command work correctly.
yatsuk@192.168.1.1 is localhost.

So I try this code using jcabi:

```
Shell shell = new SSHByPassword("192.168.1.1", 22, "yatsuk", "passw");
String stdout = new Shell.Plain(shell).exec("scp -r ~/dataIn yatsuk@192.168.1.1:~/dataOut");
System.out.println(stdout);
```

And this code by JSch:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
Session session = jsch.getSession("yatsuk", 192.168.1.1, 22);
session.setPassword("passw");
session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("scp -r ~/dataIn yatsuk@192.168.1.1:~/dataOut");
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.connect();

while (!channel.isClosed()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Both return me:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

Simple commands like `echo 1 > 1.txt` works perfectly.
Maybe something I do not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automating an execution of an interactive command is a sign of a bad design. Anyway...

---

The `scp` will prompt your for a password in an interactive session/terminal only. For security reasons, it won't read the password from a plain standard input.

So you have to enable an interactive session/terminal.

In JSch, you do that by calling `.setPty`:

```
channel.setPty(true);
channel.connect();
```

---

Similar question: [Use JSch sudo example and Channel.setPty for running sudo command on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968805/850848).

---

Another approach is using `expect` or `sshpass` tools: [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50096/850848)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scp` is looking for a password in your `~/.ssh` and can't find it there. You should provide it again to `scp`. Something like this: [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)