# Jsch and sudo command

Tags: linux, groovy, sudo, jsch

I am trying to automate some operations and one of such an operation is switching to a technical user on a remote Linux machine. The procedure looks like this: log in with a "normal" user and then switch with

```
sudo /bin/rootsh -i -u techUser
```

to the technical user.

Here's my Groovy code example that I am working on:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException

class Main {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        int responseCode = 0
        String responseText = ""
        def targetHost = "targetHost"
        def targetUser = "targetUser"
        def technicalUser= "technicalUser"
        def targetPass = "targetPass"
        def targetPort = 22
        Properties configConnection = new Properties()
        configConnection.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
        configConnection.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password")
        JSch jsch = new JSch()
        try {
            Session targetSession = jsch.getSession(targetUser, targetHost, targetPort)
            targetSession.setPassword(targetPass)
            targetSession.setConfig(configConnection)
            targetSession.connect()
            Channel channel = targetSession.openChannel("exec")
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("echo 'targetPass' | sudo -S -p /bin/rootsh -i -u technicalUser")
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true)
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(baos)
            channel.setInputStream(null)
            InputStream is = channel.getInputStream()
            channel.connect()
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024]
            while (true) {
                while (is.available() > 0) {
                    int i = is.read(tmp, 0, 1024)
                    if (i < 0)
                        break
                    responseText = new String(tmp, 0, i)
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    responseText = new String(baos.toByteArray())
                    responseCode = channel.getExitStatus()
                    break
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    println("[ERROR] " + ee.getMessage())
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect()
            targetSession.disconnect()
            println("RESULT:  code: " + responseCode + ", text: \"" + responseText + "\"")
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            println("[ERROR] Exception, problem with connection: " + e.getMessage())
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
RESULT:  code: 1, text: ""
```

When I set to

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(false)
```

the result is:

```
RESULT:  code: 1, text: "/bin/rootshSorry, user targetUser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as technicalUser on targetHost."
```

When I remove the password from the following line:

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("echo '' | sudo -S -p /bin/rootsh -i -u technichalUser")
```

The result is:

```
RESULT:  code: 1, text: "/bin/rootsh/bin/rootsh
Sorry, try again.
/bin/rootsh
/bin/rootsh
sudo: pam_authenticate: Authentication information cannot be recovered"
```

And when I set the following command:

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p /bin/rootsh -i -u technichalUser")
```

There is no response at all as the process is running all the time (the process is waiting for password maybe)

If someone has already solved such an issue or a similar one, I would really appriciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a password to `sudo` with input redirection, at least not with the default configuration.

Hence, this cannot work:

```
echo 'targetPass' | sudo -S -p /bin/rootsh -i -u technicalUser`
```

Did you even try it in the interactive terminal? I assume it would not work there either.

---

You have to write the password to the channel input stream (called "output stream" in JSch).

See the official [JSch Sudo example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html).

You may need to enable TTY/PTY. See [Use JSch sudo example and Channel.setPty for running sudo command on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968805/850848).

Comment: Many thanks for a comprehensive explanation. The project has been cancelled so that I didn't continue the investigation on this issue. I suppose the tips you gave would help me with this, that's why I marked your answer as solution to this issue. I hope your tips will help other users.